# Nginx rewrite part of URL with GeoIP variables

Tags: variables, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a URL like this:
https://example.com/home/anything/whatever

I need to rewrite this URL and replace the /home/ part with the variables from GeoIP and http-request-language:
https://example.com/ch/de/anything/whatever

I have a location match on the root that already does this and this works:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ $location_uri$lang permanent;
}
```

Now i need this for the case above and i used:

```
location ~ /home/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/home/(.*)$ /$location_uri$lang/$1/ permanent;
}
```

The original reqeust part of the URL ($1) is not added to the end of the URL:
https://example.com/ch/de//

If I remove the 2 variables $location_uri and $lang and replace them with a fix text (/ch/de) it works.

Is it possible to have these variables in the rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with 2 rewrites:

```
location ~ ^/home(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/home(.*)$ /$location_uri$lang$request_uri permanent;
}

location ~ ^/ch/de/home(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)/home(.*)$ $1$2 permanent;
}
```

First I rewrite /home/ with the GeoIP vars and add the whole request URI including /home/.
Then I make another location-match on the target-URI and remove the /home part.